# Facebook Login with Open Graph

Tags: facebook

```
 //if user is logged in - do this
```

`function login() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {  
        document.getElementById('fb-info-block').innerHTML = 
        "Welcome, " + response.name + ".<br /><br />" +
        "<fb:like href = 'www.whitbreaddesign.com' show_faces = 'false' width = '100' action = 'like' colorscheme = 'light'></fb:like>";
    });
}`

Can someone tell me how I can add the facebook users profile pic to the above code...After someone connects to my site they will get a Welcome, (their name) to my site....How can I also add there profile picture after Login along with the Welcome note?

Answer (score 1):

I hope by now you've solved this but if not you need to use the access token supplied by the getLoginStatus response.
Check out: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api
The example links for Users, Pages, Events etc are misleading. If you hover over the links you'll see that Facebook adds "?access_token=%TOKEN%" to each link. That's what you'll need to do.

You function will probably look something like this depending on how you work it.
Hope this helps.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function()
  {
   FB.init({ appId: 'Your App Id', status:true, cookie:true, xfbml:true });
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if(response.session){
     /* Fetch Access Token Data Here and set to Global Var */
     var access_token = response.session.access_token;
     /* Other Init Functions */
    }
   }); 
   function login() 
   {
    FB.api('/me', function(response){  
     /* Use Access Token Data Here */
     document.getElementById('fb-info-block').innerHTML = (
      "Welcome, " + response.name + ".<br /><br />" +
      '<br/><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token='+ access_token +'"/><br/>'+
      "<fb:like href = 'www.whitbreaddesign.com' show_faces = 'false' width = '100' action = 'like' colorscheme = 'light'></fb:like>"
     );
    });
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/me/picture">
```

Comment: "Welcome, " + response.name + ".<br /><br />" + '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/me/picture">' + ...

Comment: Thanks...the image does not show...you can tell pic should be there but no dice...any other suggestions...this was the closest so far...ugh

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use fbml tags:

fb:profile-pic and fb:name
(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

And once, you put that FBML inside your div, you may need to call
FB.XFBML.Parse() javascript function. 
(It pre-exists as I assume you must have included facebook's javascript by now)

Answer (score 0):

The me shortcut will only work if the person is logged in to fb.  You can also use their facebook Id:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/220439/picture">
```

[image]

Comment: I want the user to see their profile pic after login only...Is this possible?